# 403 after pointing A-Record of subdomain to IP of other server

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, web-server, apache2, subdomain

I have two servers **X** and **Y**.

---

**Server X:**

I have a VHOST for the subdomain *test.api.konfigurator.company.de* pointing to a directory which simply has a **index.html** containing the word "it works!".

First I tested it locally, by editing my **hosts** file in windows. That worked, the text "it works!" is showing if I call *test.api.konfigurator.company.de* from the browser.

So this made sure that the VHOST works. I deleted the record from my "hosts" file again.

---

**Server Y:**

I created a subdomain *test.api.konfigurator.company.de* from cpanel.

The process of creating the subdomain also created the A-Records.

I added this additional A-Record to `company.de`:

```
test.api.konfigurator.company.de.   300    A    3.70.50.1XX
```

If I ping *test.api.konfigurator.company.de* then I get 3.70.50.1XX so that worked.

---

So everything should be ready.

**Expected behaviour:**

If I open *https://test.api.konfigurator.company.de* from the browser, then the content "it works!" should show.

**Actual behaviour:**

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
> use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

---

VHOST:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.api.konfigurator.company.de

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/company/test.api.konfigurator.company.de/public

        <Directory /var/www/company/test.api.konfigurator.company.de/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api_company_konfigurator_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api_company_konfigurator_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Please provide the configuration files of your webserver.

Comment: Which files exactly?

Comment: That vhost is for HTTP, yet you try to access it with HTTPS. Where is your HTTPS VirtualHost block?

Comment: You are right! If I call it with http then it works! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have a VirtualHost block for HTTP on port 80, yet you call your server via HTTPS. Since Apache can't find a matching VirtualHost the default VirtualHost is used.

Add a VirtualHost for HTTPS on port 443.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I got the same error again today even on both http and https, so there must be something else going on. I even set all folders and files to chmod 777 for testing, but it makes no difference. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I figured out that the IP of server X changed and the A-Record is pointing to an old IP now.